# Ruby on Rails: Can't implement Star Rating system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependencies, strong-parameters, rating-system

I'm trying to add a simple Star Rating system for my app having taken [this tutorial](http://camjuarez.com/posts/star-rating-system-with-ajax-and-remote-forms) for an example. I have User, Hotel and Rating models. Dependencies are:

(rating.rb)

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hotel
```

(hotel.rb) & (user.rb)

```
has_many :ratings
```

And with the following code in hotel view I get this error:

> NameError in Hotels#show
>
> undefined local variable or method `user' for Class...

(in the line with **<%= form_for**...)

**Hotel view** (show.html.erb):

```
      <% form_id = "hotel_#{@hotel.id}_rating" %>
      <% if signed_in? %> <!-- To avoid throwing an exception if no user is signed in -->
          <% user_id = current_user.id %>
      <% else %>
          <% user_id = -1 %>
      <% end %>        
          <%= form_for @hotel.ratings.find_or_create_by_user_id user.id, 
                      :html => {:id => form_id, 
                      :class => "star_rating_form"} do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :hotel_id, :value => @hotel.id %>
              <% if signed_in? %>
                  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
              <% end %>        
              <%= f.hidden_field :stars, :id => form_id + "_stars" %>
          <% end %>
      <% (1..5).each do |i| %>
          <li class="rating_star" id="<%= form_id %>_<%= i %>" data-stars="<%= i %>" data-form-id="<%= form_id %>"></li>
      <% end %>
```

Ratings controller is:

```
def create
end

def update
end

def rating_params
  params.require(:rating).permit(:stars)
end
```

Migration file is:

```
create_table :ratings do |t|
  t.integer :stars, :default => 0
  t.references :store
  t.references :user
end
```

Comment: Can you give us the rest of the error message?

Comment: Of course, 
> NameError in Hotels#show 
Showing /home/mks/rails_projects/hotels/app/views/hotels/show.html.erb where line #33 raised: 
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0xbe49390>:0xb6314e74>

Comment: At which line did that error raised?

Comment: @Pavan, It's at the line with form_for, more precisely - on a phrase '@hotel.ratings.find_or_create_by_user_id user.id'.

Comment: `@hotel.ratings.find_or_create_by_user_id user.id` is the error - probably because `user` is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search on find_or_create_by, I changed line with 'form_for' into

```
<%= form_for @hotel.ratings.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id)
```

That solved the issue!

Thanks to all for your support!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the error seems to be here:

```
@hotel.ratings.find_or_create_by_user_id user.id
```

--

**user_id**

The problem is your `show` view doesn't have access to a local variable called `user`

This variable should either be defined in the `controller` (which would mean it has to be an `@instance variable`, or should be a helper (such as `current_user.id`)

The fix should therefore be as follows:

```
<% user_id = user_signed_in? ? current_user.id : "-1" %>

<%= form_for @hotel.ratings.find_or_create_by_user_id user_id ...
```

This should get it working for you with the code you have provided. As you've not provided the `new` action from the controller, I don't know whether the supporting structure for the code will be correct or not.

Comment: Now it's >> undefined method `find_or_create_by_user_id' for
 #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>

Comment: Okay! So what are you trying to do with this? Why don't you try to call that method directly on the `Review` model itself?

Comment: Solved this issue by changing that line into this: <%= form_for @hotel.ratings.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id). Thank you for your help!!!