# Can't find user without ID - form error in Rails 4 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm working on "Edit profile" part with Ruby on Rails.

the `route.rb` is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'courses/index'

  get 'courses/new'

  get 'courses/edit'

  get 'courses/show'

  get 'course/index'

  get 'course/new'

  get 'course/edit'

  get 'course/show'

  get 'sessions/login'

  get 'sessions/main'

  get 'sessions/profile'

  get 'sessions/setting'

  get 'users/new'

  get 'home/index'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'home#index' 

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
     resources :courses

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  match '/about', to: 'home#about', via: 'get'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
  match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)', via: 'get'
  match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new', via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: 'delete'
  match '/main', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
  #match '/profile', to: 'sessions#profile', via: 'get'
  match '/setting', to: 'sessions#setting', via: 'get'


  match '/editname', to: 'users#edit', via: 'get'  

  match '/show', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'
  match '/profile', to: 'users#profile', via: 'get'
  #match '/info', to: 'users#info', via: 'get'
  #match '/changepass', to: 'users#edit', via: 'get'
end
```

My `users_controller.rb` is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :check_if_signned_in, only: [:show, :delete] 

  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was sucessfully created!'
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])   
  end



def edit 
  #@user = User.find(current_user.id)
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end


def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
    sign_in @user_params
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    def signed_in_user
      redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in." unless signed_in?
    end

end
```

And, the `sessions_controller.rb` is:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])

    if user.nil?
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email or password."
      render :new
    else
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to signin_path
  end

end
```

the `edit.html.erb` is:

## Editing profile

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">

        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>

        <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

        <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

the `sessions_helper.rb` is:

```
module SessionsHelper

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def sign_out
    session[:user_id] = nil
    self.current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def deny_access
    redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Please sign in first."
  end 

end
```

The error is: in the code below

```
def edit 
  ***@user = User.find(params[:user_id])***
end
```

it Couldn't find User without an ID

How can i fix this problem please?

And moreover, the version of my rails is: 4.1.2, it seems the thing `"update_attributes"` doesn't work, is that true? How can I make "edit profile" function without using `update_attributes` please?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` should be `@user = User.find(params[:id])` ?

Comment: No, I did use @user = User.find(params[:id]), but it doesn't work. but my session method used "user_id".

Comment: please show `routes.rb`

Comment: ok, u can see the routes.rb now. @Зелёный

Comment: very bad routes, add `match '/editname/:id', to: 'users#edit', via: 'get'`  and use `User.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: if i do it, then in my profile.html.erb, the thing " <%= link_to "Edit name", editname_path %> " will not be working  @Зелёный

Comment: because you should pass `user_id` in `editname_path()`

Comment: in the route.rb? or in edit.html.erb, i have to change it to: "<%= link_to "Edit name", editname_path(user_id) %>" ?? @Зелёный

Comment: not in route.rb, you should pass variable `user` like `@user.id` before create variable with user `@user = User.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: and all routes should contain `:id` anchor, you need find in db user by `id`, `match '/show/:id', to: 'users#show', via: 'get'`, `match '/profile/:id', to: 'users#profile', via: 'get'` but i can not see `profile` action in users controller.

Answer (score 0):

**Routes**

Firstly, you'll be much better DRYing up your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :courses, only: [:index, :new, :edit, :show]
resource :course, only: [:index, :new, :edit, :show] #-> singular resource (not sure if you want)

resources :sessions, path_names: {new: "signin", destroy: "signout"} do
   collection do
      get :login
      get :main
      get :profile
      get :setting
   end
end

resources :users, path_names: {new: "signup"} do
    collection do
        get "main", action: :new
    end
end

resources :home, only: [], path: "" do
   get :about
end
```

You have to remember Rails, and by virtue, its routing structure, is [resource-based](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) (resourceful). This means *everything* you do needs to be centered on an `ActiveRecord Object` (oft called a "resource") - this is why Rails' routing is based on `resources` :)

Your routes were NOT resource-based, and hence *very* confusing

--

**Fix**

When you receive the error:

> Couldn't find User without an ID

It basically means you aren't passing the required `ID` parameter to your controller, hence preventing your application from being able to identify the object required to populate your form.

This will either be caused by not passing the `params[:id]` to your `/profile` controller, or you're calling the wrong variable name

-

I would initially look at your routes

You need to appreciate the importance of [`collection`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) vs `member` routes - `member` routes are basically designed for individual element. I believe you're not passing the parameter your `edit` action needs, hence preventing your application from assigning a value to the `@edit` variable

You're either going to need to use a `session` to access the `User.id`, or use a **member route** (which will pass the `id` in the url)

Comment: Come over here mate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834469/ruby-on-rails-cant-implement-star-rating-system

Comment: Thanks Pavan - will check out in a little bit!!